# cURL to call REST Api

Tags: bash, curl, bamboo

So I want to call a REST API from Bamboo after a deployment has completed.
This API needs a username and password but it can't be stored in Bamboo as it seems it can be viewed in the Bash History of the Build agent.

I intended to use a script task and execute something like

```
curl -f -v -k --user "${bamboo.user}":"${bamboo.password}" -X POST https://bamboo.url/builds/rest/api/latest/queue/project_name"/
```

This would make the REST call.   But the username and password is a problem.

I do have the option, however of using a PEM file.  It can be provided so does anyone know if this can be used in conjunction with the cURL?

**--OR--**

One other thought- could I encrypt a password within a file in my source control, and somehow decrypt it on the build agent, and then have curl use the file instead of reading the password from the command line?  How would this look in cURL?

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: I have no idea of bamboo, but there's certainly no such thing as member access like `${bamboo.user}` in bash. There's no OO in bash, unless you do something interesting (and even then there won't be member access with dot). But of course you can save things in an associative array if you're using bash 4+.

Comment: could you use curl to read in the username and password from a file?

Comment: I don't know such an option, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Read the man page yourself. But if you know the format of the file, of course you can retrieve them with a suitable amount of scripting. Honestly I don't fully understand the question (how you can have a pem file — usually for certs and keys, as far as my knowledge goes — that stores username and password for HTTP Basic authentication...)

Comment: can I use a PEM file to decrypt a file and get a password from it?

Comment: Probably. I'm no expert on this; I always encrypt files with GnuPG.

Comment: so I can encrypt a text file with a password in it, then use some bash command to decrypt it to plain text.  Then somehow read the PW and use it in a REST call?

Comment: Why not? (Stupid 15 char limit.)

Comment: As you are already using a variable named password, Bamboo will hide this value. You could execute the command with an "echo off - or @", like this: `@curl -f -v -k --user "${bamboo.user}":"${bamboo.password}" -X POST https://bamboo.url/builds/rest/api/latest/queue/project_name"/` in order to prevent these values to be shown in the log history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command seems to have an extra quote at the end of your command

Using a pem file to authenticate with curl:

```
curl -E /path/to/user-cert.pem -X POST https://bamboo.url/builds/rest/api/latest/queue/project_name
```

The file should have both private key and public key inside.

Comment: is this all there is to it, I just have to provide a path to the PEM file?  what does the PEM file need inside, a username and password?

Comment: Never mind then. The PEM file should be 2 certificates (public+private) with which you should authenticate against the server. But if you don't know what this is, you should try to resolve your problem with username+password.

Comment: any ideas how to do that, encrypt a file, then decrypt it using script, read contents, and use those contents in curl?

Comment: Where do you want to keep the encrypted file?

Comment: will store in it source control, and Bamboo can pull it down.  Then if I can get the code to decrypt it, read the PW and use that PW in the rest call some how...